# Retornando InternalServerError uma lista de Tuple

Tags: c#, http-request, servidor

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Gravar()
{

   List<Tuple<string, string>> statusRetorno = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

   statusRetorno.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("1245", "OK"));
   statusRetorno.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("1468", "ERROR"));
   statusRetorno.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("7548", "OK"));

   return Ok(statusRetorno);  
}
```

Tenho que mudar o código acima:

- Caso todos os Tuple forem "OK" retorno

  > return Ok(statusRetorno)
- Caso tiver um "ERROR" tenho que retornar

  > InternalServerError(new Exception(statusRetorno)

Tenho o seguinte erro, se tentar retornar 'InternalServerError'

> Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List(System.Tuple' to 'string'

Qual seria a melhor forma de retornar essas informações?

Comment: Vai ter que criar uma exception customizada pois a exception padrão não recebe o parâmetro de List<Tuple<string, string>> no construtor como o LINQ já mencionou

Answer (score 2):

Não existe nenhum [construtor de `Exception`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.-ctor) que receba uma lista de tuplas.

Os construtores disponíveis são

- [**`Exception()`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Exception__ctor)
- [**`Exception(String)`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Exception__ctor_System_String_)
- [**`Exception(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Exception__ctor_System_Runtime_Serialization_SerializationInfo_System_Runtime_Serialization_StreamingContext_)
- [**`Exception(String, Exception)`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Exception__ctor_System_String_System_Exception_)

Se você explicar o que está tentando fazer, posso tentar te ajudar a adaptar o código.

No mais, acho que você vai ter que escolher um formato para estas informações e construir uma string com isso.

Algo como:

```
return InternalServerError(new Exception("1245 OK\n1468 ERROR\n7548 OK");
```

Comment: LINQ, melhorei a pergunta, para melhor entendimento do meu problema.